# Code Interruption Converting Macros to VBA

Tags: ms-access, winapi, vba

I am trying to figure out how to get VBA code to continue after being interrupted by a popup inquiring if I want to convert.  I think I can figure out how to handle the first and subsequent popups that appear via the Windows API.  However, I can't figure out how to put focus on my code when the popup appears so I can't run the line "MsgBox FindWindow(vbNullString, "Convert macro: " & m.Name)."  Is there away for the code to continue running?  I know that I will have to add a loop to check for the popup with the title "Convert macro: " & m.Name.  Below is the code I have so far.

```
Sub ConvertMacrosToVBA()
Dim strDB As String
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Dim m As Object

strDB = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\testme.accdb"

Set appAccess = New Access.Application
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase strDB


For Each m In appAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros
    appAccess.DoCmd.SelectObject acMacro, m.Name, True
    appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertMacrosToVisualBasic
    MsgBox FindWindow(vbNullString, "Convert macro: " & m.Name)
Next
Set appAccess = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Which call is showing the popup, and does it have a parameter to force the operation without showing a UI?

Comment: appAccess.DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdConvertMacrosToVisualBasic causes the popup to appear.  My research indicates that there is no parameter to control the popup.

Comment: Does this solve your issue: [Turn action query confirmation messages on or off](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-action-query-confirmation-messages-on-or-off-e58e4bba-9d54-4b9d-b962-9eca048e5335)? (Apparently only applies to Access 2007/2010.)

Comment: No.  That setting pertains to action queries such as append, delete, and update queries.